# minDate is not being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this jQuery UI datepicker which I've used before. For some reason it will not work on this project. It prints the date correctly and I simply do not see why it wont work.

I've managed to get it to somehow react on the change, but if I set the date to after the 11th it won't let me change anything in the second datepicker. If I pick a date before the 11th it does not set an minDate (or not for what I can see)

I can console log it and it returns the correct format.

Tried my old code from an older project. It does not work here, but on the other project it does?

I've tried using 'destroy' on the datepicker.
I've tried setting it as an option.
I've tried setting the mindate from a function outside the onSelect.

```
// Check for changes in dates
jQuery('.project--create-datestart, .project--create-dateend').datepicker({
    language: 'da',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) 
{
    jQuery('.project--create-dateend').datepicker("destroy");
    jQuery('.project--create-dateend').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(formattedDate)})


    jQuery('.project--create-button').attr('disabled', false);
    jQuery('.project--create-button').addClass('success');

    needToConfirm = true;
}
})
```

I need to get the first datepicker to set the minDate on the second datepicker.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(new Date(formattedDate))`? I'd expect that it parses days as month and month as day. Are you using different datepicker than [this one](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? I've tried to reproduce your issue but this one required `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'`

Comment: @barbsan Yes. It outputs the date in the correct format dd-mm-yyyy. Both on start datepicker and end. It's like the second (end) datepicker just does not want to listen...

Comment: `new Date("dd-mm-yyyy")` returns Date with month set to dd and day to mm, I didn't asked whether the format of `formattedDate` is correct,  I asked you to see the Date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".project--create-datestart").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+2y',
    language: 'da',
    onSelect: function(date){

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

       //Set Minimum Date of project--create-dateend After Selected Date of project--create-datestart
        $(".project--create-dateend").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        $(".project--create-dateend").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+2y' );

    }
});

$(".project--create-dateend").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    changeMonth: true
});
```

Comment: For me it returns TypeError: t.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: It should work. Try this one separately.

var start = new Date(document.getElementById('project--create-dateend').value);
 var y = start.getFullYear();

Answer (score 0):

you can try these code may be help for you.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <b>From :*</b><br>
            <p><input title="From Date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control fromDate" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fromDate" id="fromDate"></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <b>To :*</b><br>
        <p><input title="To Date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control toDate" oninput="this.className = ''" name="toDate" id="toDate"></p>
 </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    defaultDateValidation();
});
function defaultDateValidation(){    
    $(".fromDate").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }); 
     $(".toDate").datepicker({ 
             dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
     $(".fromDate").change(function() {
            test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            testm = new Date(test.getTime());
            testm.setDate(testm.getDate() + 1);
            $(".toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", testm);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `setStartDate` instead of `minDate`